# Windows 10 takes two minutes for network identification at boot

Tags: windows, networking

Since I have switched to Windows 10, I always have to wait about two minutes before I can use Internet. The LAN icon looks like it is connected:

[image]

but if I click on it I see:

> Network identification...
>
> Connected

After each boot it takes about two minutes to change to:

> Network
>
> Connected

Is this normal? I am used to accessing the Internet right after booting.

More information:

- I do not need to login manually to an ISP
- I have a DSL Internet connection
- I have a dual boot computer with Win10 and Ubuntu 18.04 - on Ubuntu I am connected with the internet right after boot
- I have a Laptop with Windows 7 and a Smartphone, both have access to Internet right after boot
- I only have the issue with this Windows 10 system and the problem existed right from the beginning.

Comment: What type of internet confection do you have (do you need to login to ISP each time, or confection to a router...)? Was it better before? Do you have the same issue with other devices too?...

Comment: @MátéJuhász thanks for asking, I have added more details to the question.

Comment: @Adam for testing purposes, assign a static IP address to your network card. Does the problem still occur?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I have assigneda static IP. Since I done that, I don't have the problem anymore. Thanks for that idea!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the reason it's taking time after startup for your Internet connection to work is that your computer is having difficulty getting assigned an IP address. You should check for an updated network card driver.

The automatic assignment of an IP address and DNS servers needed to gain Internet access is usually done by your local router using the DHCP protocol. Sometimes problems with the router can lead to delays in address assignment, though in your case I would suspect the NIC drivers first since other devices on your network don't have a problem.

Alternately, on a smaller network you may wish to assign your machine a static IP address and DNS server entries, bypassing the need for a DHCP-provided assignment. This should solve the problem instantly.